# Simple update query return Error [512] [S0001]: Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, subquery

I'm trying to update a column on a table with a simple query like this:

```
update tes_off_ven
set delivery_date=null
where company_id ='A01' and  registration_year = 2022 and registration_number = 183
```

but SqlServer return the following error:

```
SQL Error [512] [S0001]: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

The error is returned only if I try to update a specific record, but works fine with another record, for example with the following where clause:

```
where company_id ='A01' and  registration_year = 2022 and registration_number = 182
```

But there is another strange behavior...the supersimple/supermassive update query without any where clause

```
update tes_off_ven
set delivery_date=null
```

works fine!

The `tes_off_ven` table the has the three fields `company_id`, `registration_year` and `registration_number` in primary key and many tables are linked with `tes_off_ven` by theese fields.

If I truncate all `tes_off_ven` linked tables the update query works fine.

Comment: Fix the `UPDATE` trigger on your table. It apparently assumes only single row updates.

Comment: Hello Fabio. Have you got triggers over your table ?

Comment: Further reading in regards to the comment from @DanGuzman : [Bad Habits to Kick : Abusing triggers](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers) & [The Silent Bug I Find in Most Triggers](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/)

Comment: Yes!! It was a f****** trigger!! Thank you!!

Comment: Do you mean fantastic trigger ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @Dan Guzman and @Delta32000 the problem was due by a trigger.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).